# How much time passes during Season 1?

Tags: orange-is-the-new-black

In the first episode of [*Orange Is the New Black*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2372162/) they mention that Piper has a 15 month sentence. In the last episode of Season 1 it's Christmas. Are there any hints or comments I might have missed that indicate how much time has passed?

Comment: I haven't read the memoir, so I don't know how accurately the show tracks to real life, but her [entry date to the prison was Feb 4, 2004](http://www.marieclaire.com/celebrity-lifestyle/articles/drug-trafficking-federal-prison-3)

Comment: Perhaps this may help someone deduce the answer, Pipers friend (on the outside) has her baby during episode 9 (if I remember), which is also set during Thanksgiving. She is already pregnant when Piper first goes to prison, I just don't remember if they mention how far. The final episode IS set at Christmas.

Comment: Halfway through season 2 Piper comments that she has served 5 months, and at that point in the series at least 4 weeks have passed

Comment: @queeg which episode is that? Also you should post this as an answer, not a comment, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the answer is between 3-4 months. I hope that's accurate enough for you. This is based on :

Halfway through season 2 (I can't remember which episode) Piper mentions she's served 5 months of her sentence. At that point in the series at least 4 weeks have passed based on events that have transpired.

Season 1 ends at Christmas, and Thanksgiving is episode 9.

Season 1 episode 8 has Pipers friend giving birth, at the beginning of the series she is heavily pregnant, although it's not mentioned how far along this pregnancy is, friends with experience tell me 7 months would be a safe estimate.

Totting all that up gives an approx answer of 3-4 months passing in series 1.

I wouldn't be surprised if the timeframe was kept deliberately ambiguous though to allow as many future series as is possible/profitable.

Comment: I think this is as likely an answer as there is. Definitely +1 for the last paragraph.